# onClipEvent handler causes an error in Flash IDE / AS2

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I made a flash movie with different layers, on the first layer i add a action script by pressing F9 `stop();` & as it works it stop movie.

now on the next line of the same layer i write this
 `onClipEvent (mouseUp) {
    new_mov.parent.play();
}`

But it shows me error that its for movie instance, & if i create a movie & then copy my frames & enter it in the move it **said you cant enter symbol inside symbol**

**How can i over come on this i mean, I want that when mouse hover on my movie than it starts**

Kindly help

Comment: You question is very hard to understand.  The error usually only occurs when you try to place an instance of a MovieClip on the stage inside of an instance of the same kind (which would cause an infinite loop).

Comment: can i know your email id i will send you file sir

Comment: i place all the things in the main frame

Comment: I see now... `onClipEvent()` can only be attached to a MovieClip, but not exist as a frame script.  You have to remove this from the layer, select the MovieClip you are trying to play, *then* hit F9 and paste the script.

Comment: This tutorial describes how to create a button - it might help you to get started: http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/Flash_button_tutorial_-_AS2

Comment: thank you..you rock dear;) thanks for tutorial

Comment: Is AS2 it was _parent.new_mov.play()

Answer (score 0):

now on the next line of the same layer i write this onClipEvent (mouseUp) { new_mov.parent.play();

you cant put movie clip code on the frame actions layer,